# Randomly replacement in textfile via batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a textfile (.txt), that is built like this:

```
;ARPE for Ariminum
event   plague  ARPE_RIDaba
date    RND summer
position    96, 81

;ARPE for Tara
event   plague  ARPE_RIDbbg
date    RND summer
position    34, 143
```

Now I need a batch script, which will replace all the "RND" in my file with a random number between 1 and 250 (no comma, only whole numbers). But I do **not** want every RND to become the same. I want each RND to be assigned random and independent from the others. Also, the text file is coded in UTF-8 without BOM and it **must** stay like this.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
call jrepl "\bRND\b" "Math.round(Math.random()*250)+1" /j /f test.txt /o -
```

The above will write all lines with \r\n line terminators, regardless what form the original had. If you want to preserve the original line terminators, then you can add the /M multi-line option:

```
call jrepl "\bRND\b" "Math.round(Math.random()*250)+1" /m /j /f test.txt /o -
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell the utility to save the output as another new file in another directory?

Comment: @Acroneos - Sure. The `/o -` option specifies that output overwrites the original file. Simply specify the output file you want instead. Something like `/o "c:\somePath\newFile.txt"`. Issue `jrepl /?|more` from the command line to get full documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, textfile is coded as ANSI after generation by your script. How can I make it UTF-8 without BOM encoded automatically? It has to be like this.

Comment: @Acroneos - ??? Are you sure it is modifying the output? (other than the replacement of course) All my tests show that JREPL preserves the original byte stream. The only restriction being that content with null bytes (0x00) requires the `/M` option. If you have a small sample file that is being modified, I would like to see it.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the encoding (ANSI/UTF) is only modified when I create a new file instead of modifying it with (parameter "/o -")? This is unfortunate because I have one "raw" file with variables which I have to run thourgh the batchfile from time to time and create new copies of those files with values instead of the variable names. So, if I run batch one, variable x gets replaced by value "123". Now when I run it again, variable x cannot be replaced again with another value, because it is now "123" in the textfile and not "x". Any solution proposals?

Comment: And yes, if I run that batch on a UTF-8 encoded textfile, the new output file is encoded in ANSI...

Comment: Ok, notepad++ shows me, it is ANSI, but nevertheless, the program works with those files anyway. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Acroneos - Very good - I thought it should be working! Thanks for letting me know.